Early 90s cartoon about video game characters working together
As far as I can remember there were several (like 6?) video game characters (fictional, not from real-world video games) working to achieve some goal.
Characters I vaguely remember:

Red ball with arms and legs (wearing sunglasses?) pushing boxes
Some guy with a sword
A basketball player?

The intro was showing all the characters "escaping" from their game.
It was an English cartoon, most likely from the USA. 
I hope it's not too vague.. 

Try this list - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_programs_based_on_video_games

@Tom77 thanks this helped me locate it

"Identification questions must contain sufficient detail" IMO the distinguished cast of seemingly random characters must have been a decent hint to what show it is?

Found it! 
It's Power Team of the TV show Video Power:

The Power Team is an animated series that aired along with the video game reviewing show Video Power. Steven Martiniere was the director and Jack Olesker was the developer and story editor. The cartoon series was produced by Bohbot Entertainment. The show reran on USA Network as Acclaim Masters.
Source: Wikipedia

The games weren't fictional, most of them are from Acclaim.
Characters: 

Kwirk from the game of the same name (Tomato with arms, legs and sunglasses)
Kuros from the Wizards and Warriors (Warrior with sword)
Tyrone from Arch Rivals (Basketball player)
Max Force from NARC (Policeman)
BigFoot from the game of the same name (Monster truck)




